Is there a sense in which $3.93 \times 10^{244} \approx 2.1$ or is Wolfram Alpha hallucinating this improper integral approximation?

Consider the integral
$$\int_0^\infty ((1+1/x)^x -e)^2\ \text{dx}$$
Clearly the integrand goes to zero so we can hope it might converge. One may compute the Laurent series of the integrand to find
$$((1+1/x)^x -e)^2 = \frac{e^2}{4x^2} + O(\frac 1 {x^3})$$
and therefore, the sum over $x \in \mathbb n$ from 1 to infinity would converge, and so our integral converges. I'm sure someone can also simply use the behavior of $(1+1/n)^n$ converging to $e$ as $n\to\infty$ to prove it as well. However, I'm fairly certain the true value of the integral is a small number, and the other "Result" definitely matches my intuition far more. I was thinking we would undershoot $e$ here, but it was just a guess that turns out to be at least half correct, according to Wolfram Alpha.
What is this number $3.93 \times 10^{244}$ have anything to do with the integral in question? Is there some sense in which $3.93 \times 10^{244} \approx 2.1$? How could a definite integral have precisely two values, one very large and one somewhat close to $e$ anyway, when $\mathbb R$ is a Hausdorff space? It just seems like something is logically wrong here, and I'm wondering how many others have run into problems like this.
Typically, if I were to see that an integral can be proved to converge to two distinct values in $\mathbb R$, that would be justification alone that the integral is divergent, however, in this case, I'm 100% sure the integral converges, due to the series comparison I discussed earlier. So what possibly gives here?

hallucinating is an understatement

Try pressing ‘more digits’ for another surprise. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28%281%2B1%2Fx%29%5Ex-e%29%5E2+from+0+to+infinity

Also, it shows 2.13526 momentarily when I press search, but after that the screen refreshes and changes to that absurd value

I don't think that the post belongs here. WolframAlpha is using numerical methods because you told it to approximate. Obviously doesn't do well with infinity as a bound, without some luck. Learn to trust closed-source software a bit less. There is no canonical sense in which your claimed approximation happens.

Does that interval converge from zero to 1? The integral comparison you are using (where convergence of sum implies convergence of integral) only guarantees that the interval from 1 to infinity converges, assuming it is decreasing on zero to one as well.

There seems to be no issue with the WolframLanguage, since this is the output in WolframCloud. The webpage seems to be mishandling the WolframLanguage output.

Maple makes a similar mistake. But if I integrate not to $\infty$ but to some finite value, say, 10000, the result is $2.135...$
